# Python + Flask App runs from wrong folder after run by Pycharm on 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, pycharm

#### Setup:

I have created and populated a `sqllite database` in `Pycharm`, running `Python` + `Flask` + `SQLAlchemy`.
The code works perfectly in the console, but when i run it, i get a:

> OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file

### Problem:

When i run `print os.getcwd()` in Chrome/Flask-Werkzeug:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.6\jre\jre\bin.

that is the wrong folder. The whole project, including the `.db` is in `C:\Users\Finn\PycharmProjects`.
Why is that and what do i do about it?

### Code:

```
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///temp/database.db")
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

**more Imports, DB-Setup & Classes**

class DBHandl():
    @classmethod
    def getData(self):  # Return Personen + Adressen
        q = session.query(Person, Address).filter(Person.id == Address.person_id).all()
        return q

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    q = DBHandl.getData()
    return render_template("home.html", list=q)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to change the`Run/Debug Configurations` that open up when you click on `my Project` in the upper right corner and `edit configurations`, there I changed the working directory.

Acknowledgements to both other answers! They led me on the path to figuring out what was up and you where very close!

Answer (score 5):

> Settings => Build,Execution,Deployment => Console => Python Console

Set the working directory to your intended folder.

Answer (score 2):

In PyCharm, did you change the project preferences? If you go in `File > Settings > Project: yourprojectname`, you should be able to define the root of the project and everything