# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I'm pretty new with Python and finding some issues on a trivial code.
I'm using Pycharm together with Anaconda.

This is my code:

```
posSentences = open('rt-polarity-pos.txt', 'r')

print (posSentences.read())
```

There is no issue in reading the file and printing it out when running it/terminal.

But when I try to run the same command in the console I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I so checked the directories of the console, but they seem fine and are the same of the running file:

[console setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61R4a.jpg)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Heya - What is your working directory when you run the script? It might be worth creating a variable that holds the Fully Qualified Path Name of the parent folder and prefixing your file with this?
e.g
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(\_\_file\_\_))

Comment: Also, when posting a code, don't post a picture. Copy the code here.

Comment: @YFP It's the same of the console: C:Users\tomlarey\Desktop\textan. Running it works, but through the console it doesn't. 
Ok thank you! I'll try it, even if right now I'm in trouble, I come from R which is straightforward in comparison!

khajvah Ok, I'll do it the next time since you already solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Python interpreter is run from `Desktop\textan` but the file is in `Desktop\textan\textan\` directory, so the path to the file in python code becomes `textan\rt...txt`

Comment: Thank you very much! 

I don't understand why tough: the working directory I set for the console is the same I set when running the file. 
Furthermore the code that makes me print the proper output is: 

'open("C:\\Users\\tomlarey\\Desktop\\textan\\rt-polarity-pos.txt",'r')' ,

so the full path.. 

I'd welcome your insight on that, thank you again!

Comment: Ok, I got confused about smth. My answer is wrong. Please "unaccept" it

Comment: I don't want to presume anything, but could it be a Pycharm issue: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304044/pycharm-current-working-directory?rq=1

Comment: No you don't presume anything. I know that my answer is wrong. You should accept answers in this site only when it fixed your issue.