# Stuck to connect Beautiful Soup and Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, pycharm, google-sheets-api

I'm working on Power BI and i have discoverd Python recently.

For training purpose i try to use a html data and plug in the data on Google Sheets

After that i will use this data on Power BI

I have found some greats tutorial but i'm stuck.

So i follow this tutorial https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html . But when i try to connect my json identifier Pycharm (my IDE) tell me the project doesn't find this json file.

I have tried 10 parameters. I think i miss something  but don't know what !
I have generated the right json file. i know that for sure.

It's "just" the connection issue

## start the connection with gs in py

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('parameters.json', scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)
```

The json file is on the same folder that py code. This is my error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MONNETA/PycharmProjects/untitled/premierscrapweb.py", line 24, in <module>

    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('parameters.json', scope)
  File "C:\Users\MONNETA\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\service_account.py", line 219, in from_json_keyfile_name
    with open(filename, 'r') as file_obj:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'parameters.json'
```

I hope you can help me on this :)

Comment: The error is clear - there is no `parameters.json` where it expects it to find it. Where is your json file located? Check the file name for misspellings.  try to specify full path to file.

Comment: It's on the same folder than the py code. I have allready try to specify the full path i will try again thanks

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/34304165/4046632 and the link provided in the answer

Comment: Hello @buran thanks for you help i will check