# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'register'

Tags: django, import

I am working on a Django project. I am working on the register page. When I try to import my register/views.py to my mysite/urls.py file I get an error message. ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'register'. Both files are are in the same directory.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from register import views as v
```

[image]

Adding full exception message
[image]

Comment: If you're importing to a file thats within the register directory, try `from .views import *`

Comment: Thanks that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:-

```
from . import views
```

Comment: any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please add a blank `__init__.py` file in the *register* folder.
Only then python will understand that *register* is an importable package

**Edit:**
After seeing the exception, it looks like a working directory issue in pycharms. Please try the fix mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304044/pycharm-current-working-directory)

Comment: Can you share the full exception traceback?

Comment: Just added the full exception