# Why is relative path not working in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, filepath

I can't get relative path in python3 to work
i used it before
but now when i try to read a text file in same folder(directory)
it shows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\python project\main_programm\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    open("text.txt")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'text.txt'
```

the code is just

```
open("text.txt")
```

i have no idea why it is doing this
the directory has main.py and text.txt (autocomplete works!)

so i searched online
and found a os command to find working directory

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

and i get this

```
G:\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.1\jbr\bin
```

also when i run this exact code through **terminal(cmd)**
with
python `"F:\python project\main_programm\main.py"`
i get `C:\Users\$my_user_name$`

Comment: How are you executing your program?

Comment: @khelwood yes
through pycharm

Comment: Have a look at [PyCharm current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34304044/3890632)

Comment: @khelwood 
but what when i run thru terminal(cmd)
i re edited my question

Comment: If you execute it through the terminal then `cd` to whatever directory you want before you run your script.

Comment: it's  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: You need to write it as `'./txt.txt'` not `'txt.txt'`

Comment: @HassaanAli `'./txt.txt'` is the same path as `'txt.txt'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps you out:

```
file = open('txt.txt')
content = file.read()
file.close()
```

Comment: no buddy
something is wrong
I see my instructor used this code
but on my machine it is not working 
:(

Comment: Do you see your .txt file in the upper left directory? (In pycharm itself)