# PyCharm how to get os.mkdir to work properly

Tags: python

When I run the code in terminal outside PyCharm's IDE:

```
    directory = "./exports./images"

    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)

    with open(os.path.join(directory, "test"), "wb") as f:
        f.write(b"\xff")
```

It works perfectly fine; however, when running it in PyCharm, it gives FileNotFoundError. When running this in PyCharm:

```
    directory = "./exports"

    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        os.mkdir(directory)

    with open(os.path.join(directory, "test"), "wb") as f:
        f.write(b"\xff")
```

It works perfectly fine. Why does the first one not work in PyCharm, and the second one does? And why does the first one work outside of PyCharm?

Comment: in terminal what is your  current working folder (type : pwd) ? that's the reason probably it works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304044/pycharm-current-working-directory)

Comment: No, files and directories work perfectly fine in the same directory. I'm trying to create a nested directory, e.g. /exports/images doesn't work, and /exports/ does.

Comment: Why are you adding the second dot in `"./exports./images"`?

Comment: For some reason, if /exports/ already exists and /images/ doesn't, the code that previously didn't work somehow does work.

Comment: os.mkdir(directory) throws an exception when called on folder which doesn't have existing parent directory. you can find this in official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory) help at all?

Comment: No, I actually didn't even know what the actual problem was. The same thing happens outside of PyCharm, and I wasn't aware.

Comment: You can use os.makedirs to create nested directories. You can do like is this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/273227/9041483