# os.listdir returns the error: no such file or directory even though the directory actually exists

Tags: python, directory, pycharm

This is my project files structure:

[image: hierarchy]

and this is my `main.py` script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    leukemia_dir = "../dataset/leukemia"  # if I click here, I get redirected to the folder
    file_names = os.listdir(leukemia_dir)  # << won't work
```

Unfortunately, `os.listdir(leukemia_dir)` returns me the following error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../dataset/leukemia'

If I remove `../` from `leukemia_dir`, it works. Furthermore, `os.getcwd()` returns `/Users/John/Desktop/Leukemia`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you print out your working directory (i.e., `os.getcwd()`)

Comment: Try printing the CWD from inside the script. It might be running from the project folder, rather than the `src` folder.

Comment: @Mureinik: I get /Users/John/Desktop/Leukemia. It seems the script gets executed inside the Leukemia folder, instead of src folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set working directory for projects in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304044/how-to-set-working-directory-for-projects-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're confused about the relative path. `../dataset/leukemia` is relative to the current working directory of the executing shell, **not** the file which is being run.

This means that if you run `python src/main.py` from `/Users/John/Desktop/Leukemia`, the CWD will is `/Users/John/Desktop/Leukemia`, and thus `../dataset/leukemia` resolves to `/Users/John/Desktop/dataset/leukemia`.

Simply using `dataset/leukemia` works because it is the relative path from the project root. It resolves to the absolute path `/Users/John/Desktop/Leukemia/dataset/lukemia`. Generally, you can safely assume your code is being run from the project root, so you won't need to use `..`.

Comment: I knew dataset/leukemia actually works, but my IDE won't redirect me to the folder if I click on the string

Comment: @tail I'm not a PyCharm expert, but it is likely that PyCharm does it the other way, ie: relative to the file. I'm not entirely sure how to change that behavior. You might want to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the CWD and how the script is executed, it may be safer to rely on the directory structure and the relative location of the dataset compared to the `main.py` file:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    leukemia_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'dataset', 'leukemia')
    file_names = os.listdir(leukemia_dir)
```

Comment: No such file or directory: 'main.py/dataset/leukemia'

Comment: @tail are you sure you copied that correctly? `basename` should remove the `mian.pay` part

Comment: Yes, I am. Copy-and-pasted

Comment: @tail Mea kulpa. It should have been `dirname`, not `basename`, and I forgot to up a directory (`..`). See my edited answer.